# Memory ranges overlap, when using MPI_Alltoallv

Tags: c, mpi

The task that we are trying to perform is to make a program that solves the poisson problem on p processes, using MPI. The problem appears when trying to find the transpose of a matrix, and we have to use MPI_Alltoallv, because the full matrix is divided into one smaller matrix for each process. Our code is not complete. We stopped when we got to the transpose part, because the MPI_Alltoallv gives us the error:

Assertion failed in file src/mpid/ch3/src/ch3u_buffer.c at line 77: FALSE
memcpy argument memory ranges overlap, dst_=0x7fff5d5efa80 src_=0x7fff5d5efa88 len_=256,

when running on 3 processes, and with n = 8. (mpirun -np 3 ./program 8).

Link to the source of the file that fails: [ch3u_buffer.c](http://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/browser/src/mpid/ch3/src/ch3u_buffer.c?rev=4153c8f8680eeb09a80424f2cc787e799e8040a5)

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef double Real;

/* function prototypes */
Real *createRealArray (int n);
Real **createReal2DArray (int m, int n);
void transpose (Real **bt, Real **b, int m);


int main(int argc, char **argv ) {
Real *diag, **b, **bt, *z; 
double *sndbuf, *rcvbuf;
Real pi, h, umax;
int i, j, n, m, k, nn, size, rank, err, rest, c;

/* the total number of grid points in each spatial direction is (n+1) */
/* the total number of degrees-of-freedom in each spatial direction is (n-1) */
/* this version requires n to be a power of 2 */

if( argc < 2 ) {
    printf("need a problem size\n");
    return 1;
}

//Problem size
n  = atoi(argv[1]);
m  = n-1;
nn = 4*n;

err = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); /* Initialize MPI */
err = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); /* Get nr of tasks */
err = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);    /* Get id of this process */
if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    printf("MPI failed!\n");
    exit(1);
}

int* colArray;
int* sCount;
int* sDispl;
rest = m % size;

colArray = (int*) calloc(size, sizeof(int));
sCount = (int*) calloc(size, sizeof(int));
sDispl = (int*) calloc(size, sizeof(int));

for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    if (rest < size-i) {
        colArray[i] = floor(m/size);
    }
    else {
        colArray[i] = floor(m/size) + 1;
    }  
}

sDispl[0] = 0;
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
    sCount[i] = colArray[rank]*colArray[i]*sizeof(double);
    if (i>0) sDispl[i] = sDispl[i-1] + sCount[i-1];
    // printf("Rank: %d, sCount[%d]: %d \n", rank, i, sCount[i]);
    // printf("Rank: %d, sDispl[%d]: %d \n", rank, i, sDispl[i]);
}

k = colArray[rank];

diag    = createRealArray (m);
b       = createReal2DArray (m,k);
//sndbuf  = createRealArray(m*k);
//rcvbuf  = createRealArray(m*k);
bt      = createReal2DArray (m,k);
z       = createRealArray (nn);

sndbuf   = (double  *)malloc(m*k*sizeof(double));
rcvbuf   = (double  *)malloc(m*k*sizeof(double));

h    = 1./(Real)n;
pi   = 4.*atan(1.);

for (i=0; i < m; i++) {
    diag[i] = 2.*(1.-cos((i+1)*pi/(Real)n));
}

for (j=0; j < m; j++) {
    for (i=0; i < k; i++) {
        b[j][i] = h*h;
    }
}

if (rank == 2) {
    printf("Matrise for rank: %d \n", rank);
    for (j=0; j < m; j++) {
        for (i=0; i < k; i++) {
            printf("%f \t", b[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

c = 0;
for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
        sndbuf[c] = (double)b[i][j];
        c++;
    }
}

if (rank == 2) {
    printf("sndbuf fra rank: %d \n", rank);
    for (i=0;i<m*k;i++) {
        printf("%f\n", sndbuf[i]);
    }
}   

if (rank == 2) {
    printf("sCount fra rank: %d \n", rank);
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%d \t", sCount[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("sDispl fra rank: %d \n", rank);
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%d \t", sDispl[i]);
    }
}


err = MPI_Alltoallv(&sndbuf, sCount, sDispl, MPI_DOUBLE, 
                    &rcvbuf, sCount, sDispl, MPI_DOUBLE, 
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error in MPI_Alltoallv!\n");
    exit(1);
}


// transpose (bt,b,m);


err = MPI_Finalize();          /* Terminate MPI */
if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error in MPI_Finalize!\n");
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
}

void transpose (Real **bt, Real **b, int m)
{
int i, j;
for (j=0; j < m; j++) {
for (i=0; i < m; i++) {
bt[j][i] = b[i][j];
}
}
}

Real *createRealArray (int n)
{
Real *a;
int i;
a = (Real *)malloc(n*sizeof(Real));
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
a[i] = 0.0;
}
return (a);
}

Real **createReal2DArray (int n1, int n2)
{
int i, n;
Real **a;
a    = (Real **)malloc(n1   *sizeof(Real *));
a[0] = (Real  *)malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(Real));
for (i=1; i < n1; i++) {
a[i] = a[i-1] + n2;
}
n = n1*n2;
memset(a[0],0,n*sizeof(Real));
return (a);
}
```

I guess something must be wrong with the inputs to the MPI_Alltoallv. Can somebody help me to find out what it is? Sorry if the code is a little messy.

Edit: I tried changing from MPI_Alltoallv(&sndbuf .. &rcvbuf, ...); to MPI_Alltoallv(sndbuf .. rcvbuf, ...); as somebody said, but it still gave the same error.

Comment: Can you show the source of the library you are using? I googled MPI_Alltoallv, but it is not easy to find `file src/mpid/ch3/src/ch3u_buffer.c at line 77` I think, if it would help to look in there

Comment: But one thing that overlaps: `sCount, sDispl` overlaps with `sCount, sDispl` I don't know this library, but perhaps it expects different arrays there, for sending and recieving

Comment: You don't want `MPI_Alltoall(&sndbuf, ..., &rcvbuf...)`, you want `MPI_Alltoall(sndbuf, ..., rcvbuf...)`; `sndbuf` and `rcvbuf` are already pointers to the relevant buffers.  Presumably they're located close to each other in memory, leading to the perfectly reasonable assertion error that you can't have the buffers overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

You compute the counts and the displacements given to `MPI_Alltoallv` wrongly. Both should be in units of data elements of the corresponding MPI datatype while you compute them in units of bytes:

```c
sDispl[0] = 0;
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
    sCount[i] = colArray[rank]*colArray[i]*sizeof(double);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- problem
    if (i>0) sDispl[i] = sDispl[i-1] + sCount[i-1];
    // printf("Rank: %d, sCount[%d]: %d \n", rank, i, sCount[i]);
    // printf("Rank: %d, sDispl[%d]: %d \n", rank, i, sDispl[i]);
}
```

The underlined multiplication is most likely the culprit. MPI tries to access past the allocated memory up to 7 times its length. Consecutive calls to `malloc()` within the same thread are likely to return closely located memory blocks, hence the overlap error. Do not multiply by `sizeof(double)`.